# #20 Science Work, 8th Grade

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, projectile

Problem:The potential energy of a 40-kg cannon ball is 14,000 Joules.How high was the cannon ball to have that much potential energy?

Please help me with this, I'm so confused '-'

Comment: What is the formula for gravitational potential energy?

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: conservation of energy .
Hint #2: MGH is gravitational potential enrgy